# Verifying whether a given phone number got my app installed or not?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, twitter-fabric

I use Twitter Digits (https://fabric.io/kits/android/digits) for signing up users. Once the user verifies with digit, how I can find whether he/she is registered in to my app or not?

Was thinking about sending the phone number of the digit verified user to my backend server and then set state as "installed/not-installed".

Whatsapp or Viber is able to tell whether a given contact got their app installed or not. I would like to achieve the same feature for my app.

Comment: “Was thinking about sending the phone number of the digit verified user to my backend server and then set state as "installed/not-installed".”, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

This - https://docs.fabric.io/apple/digits/find-friends.html# seems like something that could solve your problem.